# How to set a value into a variable from one class and get that variable's value from other class?

Tags: java, android, get, set, getter-setter

I want to set data into a variable of a class and want to get data of that variable in another class.

I have tested an example. But i am getting null value.

**Example class `Data`:**

```
public class Data {

    private String text;

    public String getText() {
        return text;
    }

    public void setText(String text) {
        this.text = text;
    }
}
```

**In the `MainActivity` class I do the set:**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Data data = new Data();
        data.setText("HELLO");
        System.out.println("GET from Main class: " + data.getText());

        // Call the get class method
        Test test = new Test();
        test.execute();
    }
```

**Test class:**

```
public class Test {

    public void execute() {

        Data data = new Data();
        System.out.println(" GET from Test class: " + data.getText());

    }

}
```

**Output:**

```
I/System.out: GET from Main class: HELLO
I/System.out:  GET from Test class: null
```

How do I access to the Main class get?

Thanks.

Comment: it's null because you've only set that value for that particular instance of the class. since your other class has no access to that, but creates a new one, it gets null

Comment: pass that variable as parameter to your execute method. but, seriously, if you don't know this: stop what you're doing, and start studying the basics. it'll cost you a some time, but it'll spare you more wasted time trying to figure things like this out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to say that the data variable is a static variable, that means it's the same for all instances of Data. Once you've done that, you don't need an instance of Data.

```
public class Data {
    private static String sText;

    public static String getText() {
        return sText;
    }

    public static void setText(String text) {
        sText = text;
    }
}
```

Then you call data statically. Data.getText() and Data.setText("hello")

edit:
But as Stultuske writes, you should brush up on the basics. My "solution" will fix your test but it's not a good one since making everything global will lead to a mess as soon as you start working on larger applications.

Comment: Thanks for the "solution" but as you say it is not good. I will try to pass the values by parameter to the `execute ()` method. Regards.

Answer (score 0):

It is null because you create new object from Data!!! If you want get value from Data, you must pass Data object to your Test method.

Answer (score 0):

The way it's done for now, `execute()` has no way to know the value of the object, because it's a new one for it. You've got two solutions for this :

- you can put the `text` variable in `static` : this way, the value will be shared by all the instances. Any `Data` object will be able to change the value of `text` and you will be able to changed the variable without creating an instance.
- you can also pass the `Data` object inside the parameters of the `execute()` function. This way, each `Data` object you will create will have its own `text` variable.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I will consider passing the `Data` object inside parameter.